# java replaceAll with java lambda or java stream (from String[])

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I want replace all `.ini` by empty value (`replaceAll(".ini", ""`) but with java lambda or java stream.

**Important note:** please do not post a solution with `for` loop, ... (java lambda or java stream response only).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> applications = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] strings = { "1.ini", "2.ini", "3.ini" };
    applications.addAll(Arrays.asList(strings));
    for (String string : applications) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}
```

**actual result:**

```
1.ini
2.ini
3.ini
```

**wanted result:**

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Next time I suggest posting your attempt, this is not a code delivery service.

Comment: `for` loop is perfect fit here. Why are you trying to avoid it? Is someone threatening you? Blink once for yes.

Comment: My question is 'How to use stream instand of `for` loop". minus verbose code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` to transform the input `String`s:

```
List<String> applications =     
    Arrays.stream(strings)
          .map(s->s.replace(".ini",""))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're happy modifying the `applications` ArrayList then you can use the `replaceAll` method:

```
applications.replaceAll(e -> e.replace(".ini",""));
```

Otherwise, if you want the results in a new collection then you can do:

```
List<String> resultSet = 
           Arrays.stream(strings)
                 .map(e -> e.replace(".ini",""))
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```